# How do I pass environmental variables to a Rake task invoked from another Rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have three Rake tasks invoked from another Rake task. The first Rake task requires that an environmental variable is set before it is executed.

The following works, however it means that I lose all the output from the task which is critical:

```
namespace :deploy do

  task :staging => :environment do
    `EXAMPLE=something rake db:rebuild`
    Rake::Task["rake envs:push:staging"].invoke
    Rake::Task["rake app:push:staging"].invoke
  end

end
```

How can I invoke the first task with the environmental variable AND display its output to the terminal?

Comment: Do the answers work? You should marked one as correct.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
ENV['EXAMPLE'] = 'something'
Rake::Task['db:rebuild'].invoke
```

Comment: @PedroMorteRolo, it does.

Comment: This does not work for me (rake 12.0.0). The invoked task seems to be unaware of the changes I did to the environment.

Comment: EDIT: It actually worked, my issue seems to be that I actually read the environment in the namespace of another task before I change it.

Comment: Works for me! Rails 4.x

Answer (score 4):

Use `system` instead of back-ticks:

```
system("EXAMPLE=something rake db:rebuild")
```